# Extract records which are present in two or more days in a row

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Could you please help me. I have one huge table which has this two columns

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZOuc.jpg)

I do need to list same records (cols_id) which are present for two or more days in a row. So to be more clear if i have table which has records for last 5 years i need to list all same records which are repeating for 2 or more days in table under in this case same hr_coil_id.

Comment: Please edit your question to post your data as text rather than a picture. Also, please add in the expected output based on your data.

Comment: From my point of view, sample data you posted is useless. All dates are 31/7/2009 and don't show what you described. So, yes - better sample data along with expected output would help us help you.